# Podmain-in-Podman osx host

Tags: macos, jenkins, podman, podman-in-podman

## What I'm trying to do?

To have the current setup:

- Jenkins controller (aka master) running on a container.
- Jenkins agent (aka slave) running on a container.

  - The agent should be able to run podman commands on the host machine.

## What have I understood so far:

So... from all the back and forward try and error is:

- Podman on macOS is a VM, so I need to connect to it via SSH.
- I've tried to expose the SSH connection configuration (podman-machine-default-root/podman-machine-default) to the agent container, but I'm not sure if I am on the right path to get this sorted.
- Podman has a [remote](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-remote.1.html) connection module.. so I have also tried to use that in the container agent with the same setup I have on the host machine... mounting the ssh key as a volume... and something like `podman --remote system connection add podman-machine-default-root --identity /root/.ssh/podman-machine-default ssh://root@host.containers.internal:50431/run/podman/podman.sock`, which kind of works, if you run as root... but when running the job as the Jenkins user it kind of falls apart.

## What I've tried?

Not sure if there's a better way to do this, but I've tried the following setup:

> $ uname -a

```
Darwin 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Dec 19 20:43:09 PST 2022; root:xnu-8020.240.18~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

> $ podman machine info

```
Host:
  Arch: arm64
  CurrentMachine: podman-machine-default
  DefaultMachine: ""
  EventsDir: /var/folders/rq/qy00w08s4zgcb2wyw_pnzzfd2yzr03/T/podman-run--1/podman
  MachineConfigDir: /Users/{USER}/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu
  MachineImageDir: /Users/{USER}/.local/share/containers/podman/machine/qemu
  MachineState: Running
  NumberOfMachines: 1
  OS: darwin
  VMType: qemu
Version:
  APIVersion: 4.5.0
  Built: 1681478900
  BuiltTime: Fri Apr 14 15:28:20 2023
  GitCommit: 75e3c12579d391b81d871fd1cded6cf0d043550a
  GoVersion: go1.20.3
  Os: darwin
  OsArch: darwin/arm64
  Version: 4.5.0
```

> $ podman system connection list

```
podman-machine-default  ssh://core@localhost:50431/run/user/1173348355/podman/podman.sock  /Users/{USER}/.ssh/podman-machine-default
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@localhost:50431/run/podman/podman.sock  /Users/{USER}/.ssh/podman-machine-default
```

> podman-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:latest-jdk11
    container_name: jenkins
    ports:
      - 8070:8080
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - jenkins
    restart: unless-stopped
  agent:
    image: custom-ssh-agent
    privileged: true
    user: root
    container_name: agent
    build:
      context: ./agent
    expose:
      - 22
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - jenkins
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - ./agent/.env
networks:
  jenkins:
```

> agent/Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/ssh-agent:latest-jdk11

USER root

# install podman
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  podman

USER jenkins
```

> agent/.env

```
JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=ssh-rsa AAA
```

References that I have read:

- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-clients-macos-windows
- https://rokpoto.com/podman-jenkins-agent/
- https://calinradoni.github.io/pages/210327-podman-systemd.html
- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-inside-container